# Android, XML: Show only portion of image in layout container without altering aspect ratio

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to set a background to any `layout`.
Usually, I would go on about this like here:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#@drawale/somedrawable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

But this will always make the background fit the `LinearLayout`. But what if the layout was smaller in height than the image I set as background? I do **NOT** want to destroy the image's aspect ratio but just center the image inside the layout and have the height overlap so that it isn't visible anymore.

To clarify:

Left is what happens currently, but right is how I want to to be. Since the layout container is smaller than the `imageview` or background image is, it is supposed to stay centered but only show what fits without altering the aspect ratio.

[image]

Comment: Set ScaleType centerCrop for it.

Comment: To the linearlayout itself or the image insde a linear layout?

Comment: Interesting question. When I had this same challenge, I took FrameLayouts to my advantage. I simply allowed two FrameLayouts to cut out the top and bottom end of my ImageView. It's a really crude method but I was able to achieve just what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello @Taslim, what user Piyush said before you is the solution: Just put an imageview into any layout container and set scaletype to "centerCrop". Everything else to "center" and the result is flawless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ImageView inside the linear layout with width and height match_parent and set the `scaleType="centerCrop"`

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/somedrawable"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot apply the scaletype property in linearlayout its better to use imageview to achieve this following is the link how to use [scaleType](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html) attribue, to avoid the stratching behaviour use the 9 patch image, follwoing is the link to convert your image into [9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)